# How can i show the correct answer?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command, debian

I'm working on a school stuff and the question is to : 
Use the `ls` command to list the files in the directory 'apache2/mods-available'.
List only files beginning with 'a' and have the file extension '.conf'.
List one file per line in directory.
Enter your bash code within $ () to execute it and return the response for exemple : ANSWER=$( find . -name 'filename' )

I tried to resolve the problem like this :

```
Answer = $(ls -1 apache2/mods-available/a*.conf)
```

And than i get this answer :

```
apache2/mods-available/actions.conf
apache2/mods-available/alias.conf
apache2/mods-available/autoindex.conf
```

It's unfortunately wrong because the rigth answer is :

```
actions.conf
alias.conf
autoindex.conf
```

Do someone has an idea about what's wrong? thanks :)

Comment: `cd apache2/mods-available; echo *`? I suggest to take a look at `find`.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus If the question specifies they must use `ls`, then they're pretty stuck unfortunately.

Comment: @OP, I'd imagine they wanted you to do `cd apache2/mods-available;Answer=$(ls a*.conf)`, although as Cyrus linked, `ls` isn't really the proper way to do it

Comment: @123: he need one file per line. So `ls -1 a*.conf` will do the trick.;-)

Comment: @arjun if they want one per line all they have to do is quote `$()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you!
This answer actually works for me :

```
$(ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | cut -d/ -f3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow script

```
Answer=$(find apache2/mods-available/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'a*.conf' -exec basename {} \;)
```

maxdepth is to search in the directory 1 depth

-exec basename {} \; is to get the name

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple commands in your `$()`. so simply run:

```
Answer=$(cd apache2/mods-available; ls -1 "a*.conf")
```

- do not put spaces around `=`
- quote the wildcards (so they won't get expanded to matching files in your *current* directory)
- don't parse `ls`

Answer (score -1):

Try it with `Answer=$(ls -1 a*.conf)`

Comment: @arjun as stated above, this will list all `.conf` files.

Comment: You missed to specify the directory :)

Comment: @GeorgesKayembe :  you have to `cd` to mods-available directory first. Or else if you have an option to use `find` command in place of `ls` then buddha's answer is also correct.